# Is ValidateAntiForgeryToken need in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm using WebAPI with asp.net core...
I'm wondering do I need something like ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute on my actions or an equivalent?

I'll be using bearer tokens/ JWT as part of authorizing users...

The API will be used by SPA's or mobile clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not use cookies / Basic auth, it is not necessary.
Referring to this answer on the Security Stack Exchange: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/166798/128394.

The reason CSRF exists is because browsers automatically include cookies for a domain in requests from other origins.
Nowadays you can actually control that with the SameSite property on cookies.

Since Bearer tokens are sent as Authorization headers and stored in e.g. local storage, they will never be sent automatically by the browser + other sites do not have access to your site's local storage (at least they should not, it would be a major security bug in browsers).
And thus no CSRF can happen.